# Angular - splitting variable defs into another file via external modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple requirement - split a bunch of variables into its own file and import it into another typescript file. I don't want to start creating new providers and methods - I think its too much work for the need.

My goal: Move variables to, say, `graphDefs.ts` and access them in `home.ts` as well as access them in `home.html` (template for home.ts)

I have a solution that works, but I'm not sure if:

- This approach is acceptable and is not bad practice
- Not sure if there is a way to directly make the imported variables accessible to the template file without a new variable like I did below

Would appreciate your thoughts.

My `graphDefs.ts` (there are several more of these `xxxxChartData` variables, shortened for brevity)

```
// common gauge defs

export var speedChartData:any =  {
    chartType: 'Gauge',
    dataTable: [
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Speed', 0],
    ],
    options: {
      animation: {easing: 'out'},
      greenFrom: 1, greenTo: 60,
      yellowFrom: 60, yellowTo: 110,
      redFrom: 110, redTo:220,
      minorTicks: 10,
      min: 0, max: 160,
      greenColor: '#019875',
      yellowColor: '#F9BF3B',
      redColor: '#EF4836',
    }
  };

  export var tempChartData:any =  {
    chartType: 'Gauge',
    dataTable: [
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Temp.', 0],
    ],
    options: {
      animation: {easing: 'out'},
      greenFrom: 1, greenTo: 60,
      yellowFrom: 60, yellowTo: 110,
      redFrom: 110, redTo:420,
      minorTicks: 10,
      min: -40, max: 420,
      greenColor: '#019875',
      yellowColor: '#F9BF3B',
      redColor: '#EF4836',
    }
  };
```

In `home.ts`:

```
import * as graphs from './graphDefs';
speedChartData:any;
tempChartData:any;
```

And then in the constructor of `home.ts`

```
this.speedChartData = graphs.speedChartData;
this.tempChartData = graphs.tempChartData;
```

(I am doing the above so I can access the imported data in the template file `home.html` like so:

```
<ion-col col-50>
   <google-chart #speed [data]="speedChartData" ></google-chart>
</ion-col>
<ion-col col-50>
    <google-chart #temp [data]="tempChartData"></google-chart>
</ion-col>
```

Comment: If you defined each of these as a class instead of a var you could use them also to strongly type your objects. That would then give you intellisense and better syntax checking.

Comment: Thanks. Class is a good idea. Any thoughts on how I can avoid having to map the imported variables to a new set in home.ts ?

Comment: AFAIK, it is considered "best practice" to wrap the data into local variables for binding.